# Property 'xxxx' does not exist on type <Reducer>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, state, reducers

I'm using typescript with react and trying to grab some state values from my reducer.  My understanding based on [here](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing) is that I should import the type definition from my reducers.

```
--- Component.tsx ---

import { RootState } from 'src/store/reducers'

const  authorize = useSelector((state: RootState) => {return {authorize: state.authorize}})
```

```
--- rootReducer.tsx ---

export const rootReducer = (history: any) => combineReducers({
    authorize: authorizeReducer,
    router: connectRouter(history)
  })

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
```

Clearly, I have the authorize property in `combineReducers`, but I see an error like this `Property 'authorize' does not exist on type 'Reducer<{ authorize: Map<unknown, unknown>; router: RouterState; }, AnyAction>'`.  Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks!